# PHP & AJAX - No refresh data when fetch to another page and send it as a Modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I am now sending data to another page without refresh but my problem is the modal, I cannot send it as a modal but I can send the data into text. why ?

here is an image of my page
[image]

here is my code

for ***ajax4.html***

```
This is where I submit data and perform inserts


<h1>AJAX POST FORM</h1>

    <form id="postForm">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name2">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script>

        document.getElementById('postForm').addEventListener('submit', postName);


        function postName(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var name = document.getElementById('name2').value;
            var params = "name="+name
;
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', 'process.php', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

            xhr.onload = function(){
                console.log(this.responseText);
            }
            xhr.send(params);
        }
    </script>
```

my ***ajax5.html***

This is where I fetch the data and also, here is where I want to show the modal

```
**EDIT** here is my current HTML 


            <h1>Users</h1>
        <div id="users"></div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">User List</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="user-list">
        <p>User list here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script>
var still_fetching = false;

//fetch data every 3 seconds (3000)
setInterval(function(){ 
     if (still_fetching) {
         return;
     }
     still_fetching = true;
     loadUsers();
}, 3000);

//need to update a bit this function
function loadUsers(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'users.php', true);

        xhr.onload = function(){
            if(this.status == 200){
                var users = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                var output = '';

                for(var i in users){
                output += '<div id="myModal" class="modal">' +    
                    '<div class="modal-content">' +
                        '<span class="close">&times;</span>' +
                        '<p>'+users[i].id+'</p>' +
                        '<p>'+users[i].name+'</p>' +
                      '</div>' +
                    '</div>';

                }

                //document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = output;
                document.getElementById('user-list').innerHTML = output;
                document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";  //show modal
                still_fetching = false;
            }
        }

        xhr.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

***process.php***

```
    <?php
//Connect to a database
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','ajaxtest');



echo 'Processing....';

//Check for POST variable

if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
    //echo 'GET: Your name is '. $_POST['name'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES('$name')";

    if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
        echo 'User Added...';
    }else{
        echo 'ERROR: '.mysql_error($conn);
    }
}



//Check for GET variable

if(isset($_GET['name'])){
    echo 'GET: Your name is '. $_GET['name'];
}
```

Comment: which version of bootstrap you are using and have you added jquery?

Answer (score 2):

There are some problem in your code.

1. You check the name parameter:

> if(isset($_GET['name']))

But you don't provide it when get.

> xhr.open('GET', 'users.php', true);

Provide it.

```
xhr.open('GET', 'users.php?name=shingo', true);
```

2. The response isn't a JSON string:

> echo 'GET: Your name is '. $_GET['name'];
>
> JSON.parse(this.responseText);

Comment: what do you mean? @shingo? i can pass texts but not a modal.. do you have any suggestion or solution?

Comment: can you please give me a solution sir" im really new to ajax :(

Comment: Add solution for the first problem, for the second, you need to return your own data in JSON format.

Comment: What you showed is returning a string: `'GET: Your name is '. $_GET['name']`

Comment: sir, @shingo i would really appreciate if you please edit my code thank you sir god bless

Comment: I can't! I don't know what and where data are stored... It seems you insert name into a mysql table, but you shows users' id and name in ajax5.html. so do it yourself. For just test purpose, following code may work `echo json_encode([["id"=>1,"name"=>"somebody"]]');`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your modal is using Bootstrap:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">User List</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="user-list">
        <p>User list here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Edit your JS function:

```
function loadUsers(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'users.php', true);

        xhr.onload = function(){
            if(this.status == 200){
                var users = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                var output = '';

                for(var i in users){
                output +=
                    '<div>' +
                        '<p>'+users[i].id+'</p>' +
                        '<p>'+users[i].name+'</p>' +
                    '</div>';

                }

                //document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = output;
                document.getElementById('user-list').innerHTML = output;
                document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";  //show modal
                still_fetching = false;
            }
        }

        xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Nothing is showing sir I link bootstrap but still nothing is showing , it only shows the Button and Users

Comment: plus nothing is being popup sir, the modal is automatically being shown :(

Comment: did you paste the modal html tags?

Comment: If you use the setInterval the modal will keep poping up every 3 seconds unles you want to popup every time you click the button to popup the modal

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: `
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: please see sir, also i added script links on bootstrap

Comment: Can you paste your current html file?

Comment: hello sir, please see my code above i edited it on ajax5.html i edited it and put all the links in there plus your code thanks!

Comment: Did you link link bootstrap css too?

Comment: yes sir here is the link where i get all the bootstrap's link [see here for bootstrap link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/)